# How to implement Safari-like tab view?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, tabs

I'm just wondering how to implement Safari-like tab view? Like this gif below, with dragging out and in animations.

[image: Safari's tab]

And also the **show all tabs** feature.

[image: show all tabs]

Comment: You might start with newWindowForTab(_ sender: Any?) to implement the tab view, it's able to move tabs, that I know. Rest is unclear but possible implement drag and drop to accept that functionality. http://stackoverflow.com/a/40627108/3275080 just basic tab view.

Comment: And you can drag a tab out of window to new window

Comment: The first view in the action might be WKWebView Preview Actions from WKUIDelegate class

Answer (score 1):

Some of these features (and some others for customisation) are available with this control: https://github.com/onekiloparsec/KPCTabsControl

(disclaimer: I'm the main author).

Comment: Look very interesting, will try it on my project!

Comment: Is there anything with objc? I am hardly looking for objc specifically for cocoa

Answer (score 0):

NSTabView is one of the least customizable of all the NSControl.
Many people have used the popular PSMTabBarController (open source) as an alternative, which supports dragging tabs.
As far as animation is concerned, I've never tried animating a
Drag/Drop item, but it sounds really cool... Let me know if you find a way to change a drag image once it's been created.

Comment: Apples Introduction to Drag and Drop, When the dragging session is started by using the NSView method dragFile:fromRect:slideBack:event:, NSView uses the file’s Finder icon for the image. For your own custom drags, you need to construct a suitable image. Possibilities include a semi-transparent snapshot of the displayed data, such as the selected section of text, or a symbolic representation of the data, such as a table icon when dragging spreadsheet data.

Comment: The repository of PSMTabBarController doesn't seem to be maintaned for a long time...