# How to add Tabs in a non-document-based app under macOS?

Tags: xcode, macos, tabs

I like to build an app in Swift 3 with Xcode 8 and it should enable the Apple tab bar. It is not document-based. I learned [here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/203/?time=938), that the tabs can be enabled if I override the method `@IBAction func newWindowForTab(_ sender: Any?)` for example in the window controller. To test this, I created a new project in Xcode using storyboard, added a subclass of `NSWindowController` and assigned it in the storyboard. I then implemented

```
@IBAction override func newWindowForTab(_ sender: Any?) {}
```

and the tab bar appears when the app is build. Once rebuild, I noticed that the "+"-button only appears if the tab bar was not visible when the app is closed prior to build. Is that a bug? How would I add new tabs?

Comment: with addTabbedWindow(window: ordered:)

Comment: @Dis3buted Thanks, but I can't get it to work like I want. I basically want the behavior as in Safari: there is some kind of default window that is open when the app launches and by clicking the "+"-button, another default window is added in a tab. So in a new project (non-document based), I subclassed NSWindowController and I assigned it in the Storyboard. In the Storyboard I already have a "View Controller Scene" that I like to appear for each new tabbed window. But I don't know how to correctly override `newWindowForTab` in my NSWindowController so that the view from my Storyboard appears.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok here are new files,

Appdelegate

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
}

func applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed(_ sender: NSApplication) -> Bool {
    return true
}

@IBAction func newWindowForTab(_ sender: Any?){
} // without this the + button doesn't show from start

}
```

ViewController

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override var representedObject: Any? {
    didSet {
    // Update the view, if already loaded.
    }
}
}
```

and WindowController

```
import Cocoa

class WindowController: NSWindowController {

var subview: WindowController?

override func windowDidLoad() {
    super.windowDidLoad()
    // Implement this method to handle any initialization after your window controller's window has been loaded from its nib file.
}

@IBAction override func newWindowForTab(_ sender: Any?) {

    let story = self.storyboard
    let windowVC: WindowController = story?.instantiateInitialController() as! WindowController

    self.window?.addTabbedWindow(windowVC.window!, ordered: .above)
    self.subview = windowVC

    windowVC.window?.orderFront(self.window)
    windowVC.window?.makeKey()
}

}
```

you have to add menu item and connect it to FirstResponder in menu view to newWindowForTab: action, assign key, say cmd+t to work, this example as is just adds tab from + button and window menu options work, "move tab to new window" and "merge all windows". You can drag tab out and drop back , move tabs horizontally. 
Look like it works.

done with Xcode Version 8.2 beta (8C30a)

Comment: Why are you storing newly loaded `windowVC` into `subview` variable? Just curious.

Comment: Play with it, try without, create and destroy subviews

Comment: Thanks for this! I'm also curious why you are storing newly loaded `windowVC` in the `subview` variable like @Eimantas asked too. Works just fine for me without it (xcode 9.2).

Comment: Figured it out - without the `subview` variable, you can't create more than two tabs. Thanks again

Comment: The `subview` rather makes sure the new window's controller will be kept alive. If you don't store the object, it'll be garbage-collected. Since the `windowVC` is of the same type as the event handler, though, you can just set `windowVC.window?.windowController = self` and have the "+" button and all menu items work still. See my answer below.

Comment: Don't forget to set the class to *WindowController* in the Identity Inspector on the Window.

Answer (score 11):

Conceptually, this is what happens:

- It suffices to call `NSWindow.addTabbedWindow(_:ordered:)` to add a window to the native tab bars.
- Once you put `NSResponder.newWindowForTab(_:)` into the responder chain of the main window, the "+" button will be visible.
- When you set `window.tabbingMode = .preferred`, the tab bar will always be visible.

However, there are some caveats when implementing these methods.

### Implement `newWindowForTab`

So where to add `@IBAction override func newWindowForTab(_ sender: Any?)` so you can call `NSWindow.addTabbedWindow(_:ordered:)`?

- If you use Storyboards, then put this into a `NSWindowController` subclass you own. That's the simplest way to get to an `NSWindow` to call `addTabbedWindow`.
- If you use Xibs, the `AppDelegate` will have a reference to the main window. You can put the method here.
- If you use a programmatic setup, put it wherever you know the main `NSWindow` instance.

### Make the "+" Button Work

**TL;DR:** When you initialize a new window, store the window's `windowController` somewhere. You need to maintain a strong reference in order for window events from being handled (in the controller).

I wrote a sample app with a TabManager that takes care of this:
https://github.com/DivineDominion/NSWindow-Tabbing

And a blog post with details:
https://christiantietze.de/posts/2019/07/nswindow-tabbing-multiple-nswindowcontroller/

Take into account how events are dispatched. Main Menu messages are sent down the *responder chain,* and so is `newWindowForTab`. `NSApp.sendAction` will fail for standard events if the source of the call doesn't connect up all the way -- that means, at least up to your `NSWindowController`, maybe even up to your `AppDelegate`.

You have to make sure any additional window you add is, in fact, part of the same responder chain as the original window, or else the menu items will stop working (and be greyed-out/disabled). Similarly, the "+" button stops to work when you click on it.

This is what @JohnV in the comments of the other answer called: "without the subview variable, you can't create more than two tabs". That's the effect, but it's not a real explanation. You can always create more tabs, but only from the original window/tab, not the new one; that's because the other tab is not responding to `newWindowForTab`.

"The other tab" itself is just an `NSWindow`. Your `newWindowForTab` implementation resides in the **controller**, though. That's up one level.

Adapting the code by @Peter Ahlberg, this will work:

```
class WindowController: NSWindowController {

    @IBAction override func newWindowForTab(_ sender: Any?) {

        let windowController: WindowController = self.storyboard?.instantiateInitialController() as! WindowController
        let newWindow = windowController.window

        self.window?.addTabbedWindow(newWindow, ordered: .above)

        newWindow.orderFront(self.window)
        newWindow.makeKey()

        // Store the windowController in a collection of sorts
        // to keep a strong reference and make it handle events:
        // (NSApp.delegate as? AppDelegate).addManagedWindowController(windowController)
    }
}
```

I didn't need to add `newWindowForTab` to `AppDelegate` to make everything work using Storyboards -- because this way the window controllers keep doing their job and don't need a fallback!

Comment: Nice answer, but sharing a controller makes it a nightmare to handle outlets. I was fighting with your approach, until I find a great post explaining how to use separate controllers for each tab. It turned out the blog post was yours too! Please update the answer, to at lease include a link to your post: https://christiantietze.de/posts/2019/07/nswindow-tabbing-multiple-nswindowcontroller/

Comment: Whoah, you're right. Thanks! Have rephrased the answer.

Comment: Hi I used your repo but there is a problem. Window is unresponsive. But thank you for your solution works good. Can you please answer my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69752377/cocoa-multi-tab-is-unresponsive-after-creation-of-new-tab-in-swift

Comment: @Vin would be great if you could open a GitHub issue with more details (macOS version etc.) so we can fix that

Comment: @ctietze, No problem, It's macOS Bug. The same issue happens in Finder App also.

Comment: For others, I seem to have better or more consistent behavior when I use `[self.window.tabGroup insertWindow:atIndex:]` instead of `[self.window addTabbedWindow:ordered:]`, even though the docs says the latter is a wrapper to the former.

Answer (score 0):

In case above "+" will add new tab always after first window, if you close first window then it will be recreated under current window.

there is way to get it work

```
override func newWindowForTab(_ sender: Any?) {
    let wc: NSWindowController = self.storyboard?.instantiateInitialController() as! NSWindowController
    wc.window?.windowController = self
    NSApplication.shared.mainWindow!.addTabbedWindow(wc.window!, ordered: .above)
    wc.window?.orderFront(self)
}
```

trick in NSApplication.shared.mainWindow! you always add tab to current active window.

and if we need create window at the end we should use this trick

```
let tabbedWindows = NSApplication.shared.mainWindow!.tabbedWindows!
let lastTabIdx = tabbedWindows.count - 1
tabbedWindows[lastTabIdx].addTabbedWindow(wc.window!, ordered: .above)
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that if implementing `newWindowForTab` in the app delegate (without using NSWindowController), I found the following to work the best:

```
@IBAction func newWindowForTab(_ sender: Any?) {
    let newWindow = NSWindow(...)
    ...
    app.mainWindow?.addTabbedWindow(newWindow, ordered: .above)
    newWindow.makeKeyAndOrderFront(sender)
}
```

The `mainWindow` is the NSWindow that is currently active. When `mainWindow` doesn't exist, it simply creates a new non-tabbed window, useful when for example there are no windows.