# How to make a tab bar at the top of the application by analogy with browser tabs?

Tags: swift, macos, storyboard

I want to do something like this:

[image]

When you hover over a tab, a cross should appear that closes that tab. Just like it works in browser tabs.

Is there a way to do this through storyboard or programmatically?

Comment: are you looking to do this for an iOS or MacOS app ?

Comment: @ShawnFrank MacOS

Comment: Check this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48830321/macos-swift-safari-like-tabs

Comment: Here is the solution ---> [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54326001/12778618)